# Efficient way of passing data between MATLAB functions

Tags: matlab, function, optimization, parameter-passing

I am solving a very large optimization problem. The objective function and constraint function needs numerous data. Currently I am passing the data as a structure to them.

```
myFS(X, Dat, g_Index, f_Index)  % Dat is a structure which includes many variables
```

Do you think it's an efficient way to reduce the elapsed time?

What better alternatives do exist?

Is this what the given answer, regarding to class definition, means?

```
 %% First we define the class in a separate file:
classdef myDataStructure < handle

    properties
 NRES;
 NOBJ;
 NVAR;
    end
    methods
        function obj = myDataStructure()
        end
    end
end

%% In another file where the main program is, we initialize the class.

Dat = myDataStructure();
%%  Initialize
Dat.NRES = 1;
Dat.NOBJ = 1;
Dat.NVAR = 1;
[myF, Dat_updated] = BBB(Dat);

%% Here we define the function and use the class

function [f, CalssDat] = BBB(CalssDat)
    x = CalssDat.NRES;
    y = CalssDat.NOBJ;
    z = CalssDat.NVAR;
    f = x + y + z;
    CalssDat.NOBJ = 2;
end
```

Comment: Yes, I meant this in my answer. There's just one thing to keep in mind: In your line `[myF,Dat_updated]=BBB(Dat);`, `Dat_updated` and `Dat` will be the same thing (i.e. both of them will have `ClassDat.NOBJ` equal to `2`)

Comment: That's very good. I am going to apply it on my method. Thank you @TamásSzabó

Comment: @TamásSzabó I applied your method on my problem, but it didn't reduce the `CPU time`. My initial code with `Dat Struct` takes `262` sec and with this class definition it takes `302 sec`. I tried to initialize the Dat one time in the class and another time outside of the class, but still it takes `302 sec`. I should also say that, the `Dat struct` that I use is almost huge and it passes through many functions and is updated. But still `Dat struc` seems more efficient than its `class` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, MATLAB does not actually copy the content of the data you pass to a function until the point when you modify it in the function itself - in which case it makes a local copy and that takes some CPU time.

Therefore, as long as `Dat` doesn't change inside `myFS()`, what you are doing now does not add any CPU overhead. In case you do change the values of `Dat` inside `myFS()` and want to return it, I can think of two ways to optimise it:

You can declare `myFS()` as: `function [Dat, anythingElse] = myFs(X,Dat,g_Index, f_Index)`, which should prevent matlab from making a local copy.

Another approach is to use a class that derives from `handle` and have `Dat` be a member of that. This way, whenever you pass the object containing `Dat`, you only pass the object handle and not a copy of the object itself.

Example of the second approach:

```
classdef myDataStructure < handle

    properties
        p1FromDat;
        p2FromDat;

        %   .
        %   .
        %   .

        pNFromDat;
    end

    methods
        function obj = myDataStructure()
            % Add initialization code here if you want. Otherwise p1FromDat
            % ... pNFromDat are accessible from outside
        end
    end
end
```

Than, in your code:

```
Dat = myDataStructure();
Dat.p1FromDat = 1;
Dat.p2FromDat = 1;
```

And in your `myFs()` you use Dat exactly the same way as you used before.

Because myDataStructure derives from `handle`, the data inside will not be copied when you pass Dat around.

**Do** be careful with this, because when you change `Dat` in `myFS()`, the values will be changed outside the scope of `myFS()` as well.

Comment: Thank you @tamás-szabó But I didnt understand last part. would you explain how to use class?

Comment: hmm I am not familiar with this. :(( @tamás-szabó

Comment: So, if Dat changes during calling in functions, Matlab makes a copy of it and this will impose CPU burden. But,  if I use class definition, changes in Dat does not impose CPU burden?  @tamás-szabó

Comment: @Jamaisavenir: as I mentioned in my post. If `Dat` is a data structure and you make a change to it inside `myFs()`, matlab makes a local copy of it on which it operates (does take some CPU time, depending on the size of `Dat`). If instead of a data structure you use the class based method I proposed, no copies will be made, but the changes will directly be applied in the data you pass to `myFs()`

Comment: Very interesting. I think I should learn this class definition.  One more question, lets assume I defined this Dat struc as a class variable in function A, now I passed it to function B. At this point if I add a new variable to this Dat struc (Dat.bb=1; bb was not exist in Dat before) and pass it to function C, does Matlab copy all data to C , or just directly apply the new update? @tamás-szabó

Comment: @Jamaisavenir: While class objects and structs are similar in many ways, there is also a number of differences between them. The most important one (regarding your question!) is that you _can't_ add new properties (or in other words, variables ) to an already created instance of the class.

Comment: @Jamaisavenir: If you need to do that, than there is a workaround for that: declare a _single_ variable in your class, let's call it `data`. Than treat `data` as a struct, in which case you can add additional variables to it. Than in your functions you'd do: `Dat.data.bb = 1` and that would. When you pass Dat to `C()`, you'll see Dat.data.bb as created in `B()`

Comment: That's good to know , thanks. So I need to add all sub variables in my Dat struc first (I may need to initialize some of them like this `Dat.filter=[ ];`) , then define it as class in first function (A.m) and then pass it normally to other functions and modify the Dat if its needed. Is that correct? @tamás-szabó

Comment: Not quite. I'd suggest you take a closer look to OOP in matlab: http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/object-oriented-programming.html